# How to change the gateway in pipeline

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am creating a pipeline using api manager and api cli. Now i have 3 environments and 3 servers. But gateway names are different in each server. Test gateway, qa gateway and production gateway. As my gateway name is different in environments, i have to change the value in zip file everytime i import. This is hard to automate and is there an easy way to do it?

I tried to define all three gateways in test environment and then the export zip has all three. but is there a better way to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with APICTL. When you are importing an API, environment specific parameters such as deployment environments, endpoint URLs, certificates can be changed without extracting the exported zip. By providing a params.yaml with the import command, you can override the existing configurations in the zip and during the import server will resolve the overriding values from the params.

[Params.yaml](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/advanced-topics/configuring-environment-specific-parameters/#defining-the-parameters-file-for-an-api) can be defined as below for your scenario.

```
environments:
- name: test
  configs:
    deploymentEnvironments:
        - displayOnDevportal: true
          deploymentEnvironment: test
          deploymentVhost : localhost
- name: qa
  configs:
    deploymentEnvironments:
        - displayOnDevportal: true
          deploymentEnvironment: qa
          deploymentVhost : localhost
- name: prod
  configs:
    deploymentEnvironments:
        - displayOnDevportal: true
          deploymentEnvironment: prod
          deploymentVhost : localhost
```

Provide this params.yaml as an input to the import API command.

```
apictl import api -f dev/PhoneVerification_1.0.zip -e prod --params /home/user/custom_params.yaml
```

Also i would like to suggest you to read this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/ci-cd-with-wso2-api-management/) which explains the CICD story of API Manager with APICTL tool and github or jenkins pipelines.